# Cannot find GND on 7 Segment Display Datasheet

Tags: led, transistors, components, display, 7segmentdisplay

I'm trying to use a 7 Segment Knightbright LED Display, however, after careful study of the datasheet, I'm unable to find what I believe should be the GND pin to power a segment!

http://www.circuitspecialists.com/content/52077/SA03-11EWA.pdf

Could anybody please help point this out to me.

Comment: Remember, diodes have cathode and anode, not V+ and GND.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my interpretation of this datasheet, pins 3 and 14 are the common anode pins that you would have to connect to the positive rail, and then pull down (to ground) the segments you want to light up.

Comment: Yup that's totally correct.

Answer (score 3):

[image] from the [datasheet](http://www.circuitspecialists.com/content/52077/SA03-11EWA.pdf)

This is a *common anode* 7-segment character.  It has a common high side and individual low sides.  The device driving this character would sink the current through the LEDs, which need to be lit.

There are common cathode 7-seg characters out there too, if you positively need to have common GND.  Have a look at a [datasheet for another family of 7-seg characters](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/348/la-401dn-209515.pdf).  It shows both common anode and cathode.

Comment: 1, 2, 3, jinx :P

Answer (score 1):

[image]

That's the schematic from the datasheet. Seems 3 AND/OR 14 can be used as the Common Anode.

Comment: Depending on possible heatsink and current requirements, wouldn't you want to use both 3 *and* 14?

Comment: @JYelton Maybe. These are typical ~20mA leds. Abs. Max ~30mA. Max 75 Milliwatt per led, so ~ 0.6W. Doesn't seem something to even be concerned about. That said, changed it to And/Or.